# useContext + useReducer don't cause rerender (always provide default state)

Tags: reactjs, use-context, use-reducer

In a sample mini app I have index.js which renders `<App />` (with ReactDOM.render method). And `<App />` is:

```
import { useReducer } from 'react';

import AppContext, { defaultAppState } from './store/AppContext';
import AppReducer from './store/AppReducer';

import CitiesList from './components/CitiesList';
import AddCity from './components/AddCity';

export default function App() {
  const [appState, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, defaultAppState);
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={[ appState, dispatch ]}> 
      <CitiesList />
      <AddCity />
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );  
}
```

The context is defined in a file like this (AppContext.js):

```
import React from 'react';

export const defaultAppState = { 
  cities: [
    {name: 'CityA', temperature: 20},
    {name: 'CityB', temperature: 12},
  ],
};

export default React.createContext(
  defaultAppState
);
```

And the reducer is this one (AppReducer.js):

```
import { defaultAppState } from './AppContext';
import * as ACTIONS from './Actions';

const AppReducer = (state = defaultAppState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.ADD_CITY:
      const newCities = state.cities.concat([action.payload]);
      return { ...state, cities: newCities };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default AppReducer;
```

In `<AddCity />` component I'm successfully triggering `dispatch` and update the state in the reducer. (Placed console.log just before the `return` and saw that it's what the new state is supposed to be.) However, this does not trigger re-rendering and `<CitiesList />` doesn't reflect any change - it always shows the default state.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

=====

EDIT:
Adding the code of `<CitiesList />`:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import AppContext from '../store/AppContext';

export default function CitiesList() {

  const [appState, dispatch] = useContext(AppContext);

  const { cities } = appState;

  return (
    <>  
      <h1>Cities ({cities.length})</h1>
      {cities.length > 0 &&
        // Looping the cities array and showing the actual cities ..
      }   
    </> 
  );  
}
```

Adding the code of `<AddCity />` as well:

```
import { useState, useReducer } from 'react';

import AppReducer from '../store/AppReducer';
import { ADD_CITY } from '../store/Actions';

export default function AddCity() {

  const [appReducer, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const onButtonClick = e => {
    const newCityData = { name: name, temperature: 18 };
    dispatch({type: ADD_CITY, payload: newCityData});
    setName('');
  };  

  return (
    <>  
      <input value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <br/>
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Add city</button>
    </> 
  );  
}
```

Comment: You forgot to share the code in CitiesList.
I think you didn't consume context right-way in CitiesList.
useContext(AppContext)

Comment: @ndthanhdev, I just did. Initially I didn't add it because I didn't want the initial post to be too long.

Comment: try to log `appState` under ` const [appState, dispatch] = ...`

Comment: @ndthanhdev - it always shows the default one. ... In the reducer, when I dispatch the event, I see the list changes, but in the views I always get the default ones.

Comment: I think you should share the code in AddCity too.

Comment: I think you are using useReducer instead of useContext in AddCity

Comment: @ndthanhdev - I just added the code for `<AddCity />`. Also - yes, I'm using the `useReducer` there cause I want to update the cities list. Is that a problem?

Comment: you want to update the state in the global context so you have to use dispatch from useContext.

Comment: in AddCity, try this `const [_unused, dispatch] = useConetxt(AppContext);`

Comment: @ndthanhdev - I get it now :) ... I had to use the dispatch from the context, and the Provider puts the dispatch there pulling it from the reducer ... right? ... I just tried it and it works :) ... so how about you answer and I'll accept your answer ... thus you'll make a bit more reputation ;)